# telnet to a system and verify username/password against user_acct dictionary keys: values

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
# I'm trying to telnet to a system and verify the username/password which
# is raw_input against a dictionary variable called user_acct

tn = telnetlib.Telnet()
host = "10.66.55.171"
newline = "\n"
telnet = telnetlib.Telnet(host, "23")
telnet.read_until("Username: ".encode())
telnet.write(username)
telnet.read_until("Password: ")
telnet.write(password)

user_acct = {'ADMIN':'PASSWORD','READONLY':'PASSWORD','READWRITE':'PASSWORD}
```

def **init**(self, username, password):
    telnet.read_until("Username: ")
    self.username = raw_input("Username: ")
    telnet.write(username)
    telnet.read_until("Password: ")
    self.password = raw_input("Password: ")
    telnet.write(password)

```
def __str__(self):
    return "Enter username: " + self.username + "\n" + \
           "Password: " + self.password

    if user_acct != username and password: 
     print('Invalid Login... Please Try Again')
    else:
     print('Correct Login')
```

Comment: With the existing code, I'm not sure if I'm logged in because I'll type an invalid username/password and nothing happens

Comment: If you type an invalid username, does the expected prompt from the remote system (_e.g._ `telnet.read_until("Username:")`) change?

Comment: When I type an valid or invalid username/password there is NO prompt, just a blinking cursor.

Then I close or exit and I get "Your Program is still running, Do you want to kill it?